# Bootstrap appears not to be working with my columns

Tags: html

I am currently working on my first website and I'm attempting to create a product page using bootstrap. However, it seems that the columns and rows are not working with bootstrap. Alongside with the columns not working other things aren't working properly such as the shopping cart icon. What am I missing? here is my code.

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charest="UTF-8">
<meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scaled=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="id=edge">
<title>Store</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/lightbox.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header id="store-header">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo-text">
            <h1 class="text-logo">Your Local Artist</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="logo-top">
        <h1 class="logo-text">
            Your Local Artist
        </h1>
        <h2>
            |Store
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="store-container">
        <h2>New Arrivals</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product-top">
                    <img src="./products/resize2.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Quick SHOP"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-bottom text-center">
                        <i class="fa fas-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                        <h3>Art painting</h3>
                        <h5>€100.00</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product-top">
                <img src="./products/resize2.jpg">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Quick SHOP"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
                </div>

                <div class="product-bottom text-center">
                    <i class="fa fas-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                    <h3>Art painting</h3>
                    <h5>€100.00</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-top">
            <img src="./products/resize2.jpg">
            <div class="overlay">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Quick SHOP"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Add to Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="product-bottom text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                <h3>Art painting</h3>
                <h5>€100.00</h5>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure your CSS lines include rel="stylesheet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your Bootstrap and font awesome CDN with this(I replaced and it started working)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
```